# How do I use Qt and Scons together?

Tags: qt, build, scons

I'm looking to use SCons as my prefered method of building my mainly Qt based applications.  I'm just learning SCons and I'm struggling to find documentation or tutorials on the topic.  Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

[This](http://www.scons.org/wiki/FromQmakeToScons?highlight=(qt)) is a start but is there anything better out there?

(I work mainly on Windows)

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 2):

We are using Qt4 and SCons together on Windows simply because we need SCons excellent customization possibilities. The Qt4 tools have proved themselves to be complete enough for our needs, although we do not use all facets of the Qt4 toolkit. The manual is on the [Qt4 tools web page](http://www.scons.org/wiki/Qt4Tool)

Answer (score 0):

Try [here](http://qtnode.net/wiki/Qt_with_SCons) and [here](http://www.iua.upf.edu/~dgarcia/Codders/sconstools.html).
I would suggest you though to try cmake instead. It has much better documentation and is being used by KDE.

Comment: The first lnk is just a link to the second.  The 'Qt4 Tool' has too many limitations and things left to implement.

Comment: any specific reasons as on why do you want to use scons and not cmake? documentation on using scons and qt seems to be very limited. This may be a good start: http://www.scons.org/wiki/FromQmakeToScons
Your best bet would be to try to find a Qt project that uses scons and learn by looking at its scons script.

Comment: Both links seems to be dead now. This one still works: https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/FromQmakeToScons